# How to use Repo.transaction with raw sql queries with Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am converting a Node.js app into Elixir and I am needing to use raw SQL queries within Ecto as I have some fairly complex SQL queries. I have about 10 that sit within a transaction.

I am fairly new to Elixir as well and am trying to use Repo.transaction instead of trying to roll my own transactions.

So I have about 10 of these:

```
raw_query = "INSERT INTO user_servers(user_id, server_id, server_type_code, position, active_flag, create_date, created_by)
             SELECT $1, $2, 'SERVER', (COALESCE(MAX(position), 0) + 1), 'Y', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $3
             FROM user_servers WHERE server_type_code = 'SERVER' and user_id = $4;"

Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyRepo, raw_query, [value1, value2, value3, value4])
```

If I do

```
Repo.transaction fn ->
  Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyRepo, raw_query, [value1, value2, value3, value4])
  Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyRepo, raw_query, [value1, value2, value3, value4])
end
```

And one of them fails, will it auto-rollback any queries on a failure?  Also is there a way to name those queries?

For example, maybe I want my first query to be named user_servers so when the transaction comes back I can retrieve it with {:ok, :user_servers: results} like I can with Ecto.Multi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at `Ecto.Multi`. It will allow you to name each query. It also stops the the pipeline if an earlier query fails.

```
defmodule UserServers do
  alias Ecto.Multi
  alias MyApp.Repo

  def insert(value1, value2, value3, value4) do
    raw_query = 
      ~s{INSERT INTO user_servers(user_id, server_id, server_type_code, position, active_flag, create_date, created_by)
      SELECT $1, $2, 'SERVER', (COALESCE(MAX(position), 0) + 1), 'Y', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $3
      FROM user_servers WHERE server_type_code = 'SERVER' and user_id = $4;}

    Multi.new
    |> Multi.run(:one, &query(&1, [value1, value2, value3, value4]))
    |> Multi.run(:two, &query(&1, [value1, value2, value3, value4]))
    |> Repo.transaction
  end

  def query(raw_query, values) do
    Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyRepo, raw_query,values) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey I actually figured this out already.  I am going to post another answer, with a bit more for future people, but I really appreciate you being so active on stackoverflow so far and answering all kinds of questions!

Answer (score 0):

So to add to Steve Pallen's answer I am going to add a bit more onto it just in case more people in the future have the same question.

So I built a utility class to help me with transactions:

```
defmodule ChatApp.DatabaseUtils do

    import Ecto

    def execute_and_load_into_model_from_multi(repo, sql, params, model) do
        fields = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(repo, sql, params)
            |> load_into_model(model, repo)
        {:ok, fields}
    end

    defp load_into_model(response, model, repo) do
        Enum.map(response.rows, fn row ->
            fields = Enum.reduce(Enum.zip(response.columns, row), %{}, fn({key, value}, map) ->
                            Map.put(map, key, value)
                        end)
            Ecto.Schema.__load__(model, nil, nil, nil, fields,
                               &Ecto.Type.adapter_load(repo.__adapter__, &1, &2))
        end)
    end


    def execute_and_load_from_multi(repo, sql, params) do
        fields = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(repo, sql, params)
            |> load_into

        {:ok, fields}
    end

    defp load_into(response) do
        Enum.map(response.rows, fn row ->
            fields = Enum.reduce(Enum.zip(response.columns, row), %{}, fn({key, value}, map) ->
                            Map.put(map, String.to_atom(key), value)
                        end)
        end)
    end

end
```

Essentially what these do is for

> execute_and_load_into_model_from_multi

Will map your query to a schema afterwards, you just have to pass your repo, model, and query through.  My Schema I am using is my first Multi-run which is ChatApp.Roles.RoleMasters which is the name of my schema.

The other one:

> execute_and_load_from_multi

will map your query to a map but not to a model, it will also convert the strings to atoms so you can grab the maps the same with either function.

Multi's to keep going in a transaction require an {:ok, result} the ok tells it to not trigger a rollback.

So this is what a query would look like, I am going to use everything that I can think of in this for the most amount of examples I can think of for this.

```
multi =
    Multi.new
    |> Multi.run(:role_masters, fn %{} ->
        qry = "SELECT * FROM reph.role_masters " <> "WHERE role_name = ?"
        DatabaseUtils.execute_and_load_into_model_from_multi(ChatApp.Repo, qry, ["STARTER"], ChatApp.Roles.RoleMasters)
     end)
     |> Multi.run(:role_master_parameters, fn %{role_masters: role_masters} ->
        IO.inspect role_masters
         DatabaseUtils.execute_and_load_from_multi(ChatApp.Repo, "SELECT * FROM reph.role_master_parameters WHERE role_master_id = ? AND parameter = 'ROLE_NAME'", [Map.get(Enum.at(role_masters, 0), :id)])
     end)
     |> Multi.run(:insert_server_type_parameters, fn %{} ->
        ChatApp.Repo.insert(%ChatApp.Servers.ServerTypeParameters{server_type_code: "VOICE_CHANNEL", parameter_namespace: "PERMS.VOICE", parameter: "TEST_VOICE", parameter_value_type: "FLAG3", parameter_default_value: "I", description: "Members with this permission can change their voice", parameter_role_capable_flag: "Y", active_flag: "Y"})
     end)

case ChatApp.Repo.transaction(multi) do
  {:ok, result} ->
    IO.puts "results"
    IO.inspect result.role_master_parameters
    IO.inspect result.insert_server_type_parameters
  {:error, result } ->
    #do stuff with an error
end
```

As you can see I named these queries one was :role_masters, one was :role_master_parameters, :insert_server_type_parameters.

Now in this section

> fn %{role_masters: role_masters}

You can name it like this:

> fn %{role_masters: whatevers}

As multi will match on the role_masters atom from before.

Also at the end you can see the result, well it comes out in a map of maps essentially, so my map will contain 3 maps which are named by my 3 queries:

> :role_masters, :role_master_parameters, :insert_server_type_parameters

if you need to do any with them at the end just grab them by doing this after a completion of transaction

> result.role_masters, result.role_master_parameters, result.insert_server_type_parameters

Hopefully this will help some people in the future if they need to do raw SQL.